# Add third-party library in webpack

Tags: webpack, knockout.js

I am using webpack ...I want to use 3rd party library (knockoutjs library) in my webpack.config.js file, library is saved in my local directory

I have tried using

```
const ojL10n = require("D:/SVN/trunk/core/channel/framework/tmp/ojL10n.js")
```

but i am getting error... define is not defined in D:/SVN/trunk/core/channel/framework/tmp/ojL10n.js

here is my config file

```
"use strict";

require("amd-loader");

const webpack = require("webpack"),
path = require("path");

ojL10n = require("./tmp/ojL10n.js"), //library stored in local
text = require("./tmp/text.js"), //library stored in local

 webpackConfigurationObject = {
    entry: "./entryModule.js",
    target: "node",
    mode: "development",
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            text : text,
            ojL10n : ojL10n
        },
        extensions: [".ts",".js", ".json"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dest"),
        filename: "combinedFile.js",
        library: "combinedFile",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            include: /src/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)|(dist)/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            parser: { amd: false }
        }]
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: {
            commonjs2 : "jQuery"
        },
        knockout: {
            commonjs2 : "knockout"
        }
    }
};

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfigurationObject),

compiler.run(complete);
```

Comment: Can you post your webpack.config.js?
Did you try setting your output.libraryTarget to 'umd'?

Comment: You can also try to add: `{ test: /ojL10n/, loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false' },` as rule loader

Comment: @RazRonen thank you for your reply... i have added my config file code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this question.

```
resolveLoader: {
    // This adds ./loaders/ to the list of folders where Webpack is looking for loaders
    modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "./loaders")],
    alias: {
      ojL10n: "ojL10n-loader",
      text: "text-loader"
    }
```

add resolveLoader to your webpack.config.js file